# Select element based on multiple classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a style rule I want to apply to a tag when it has **two** classes. Is there any way to perform this without JavaScript? In other words:

```html
<li class="left ui-class-selector">
```

I want to apply my style rule *only* if the `li` has both `.left` and `.ui-class-selector` classes applied.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/ - see Double Class Selector

Answer (score 714, accepted):

You mean two classes? "Chain" the selectors (no spaces between them):

```
.class1.class2 {
    /* style here */
}
```

This selects all elements with `class1` that also have `class2`.

In your case:

```
li.left.ui-class-selector {

}
```

Official documentation : [CSS2 class selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html).

---

As *akamike* points out a problem with this method in Internet Explorer 6 you might want to read this: [Use double classes in IE6 CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312022/use-double-classes-in-ie6-css)

Comment: Please note that IE6 does not like these, as it does not read the chain of classes. It will only look at the last class in the chain.

Comment: Yeah, you can't use them at all in IE6, only take longer routes to style your elements. For example, styling each class separately and using appropriate CSS specificity to override as best as you can.

Comment: what happens if there IS a space between class selectors?

Comment: @BenKoshy: It's interpreted as the [*descendant combinator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator). `.a .b` applies to all elements `.b` that have an element `.a` as their ancestor.

Answer (score 32):

Chain selectors are not limited just to classes, you can do it for both classes and ids.

**Classes**

```
.classA.classB {
/*style here*/
}
```

**Class & Id**

```
.classA#idB {
/*style here*/
}
```

**Id & Id**

```
#idA#idB {
/*style here*/
}
```

All good current browsers support this except IE 6, it selects based on the last selector in the list. So ".classA.classB" will select based on just ".classB".

For your case

```
li.left.ui-class-selector {
/*style here*/
}
```

or

```
.left.ui-class-selector {
/*style here*/
}
```

Comment: Id & Id is a conceptually strange selector.

Comment: The double ID selector is impossible I would think because it says you need to have two different IDs for the same element.

Answer (score 5):

You can use these solutions :

CSS rules applies to all tags that have following two classes :

```
.left.ui-class-selector {
    /*style here*/
}
```

CSS rules applies to all tags that have `<li>` with following two classes :

```
li.left.ui-class-selector {
   /*style here*/
}
```

jQuery solution :

```
$("li.left.ui-class-selector").css("color", "red");
```

Javascript solution :

```
document.querySelector("li.left.ui-class-selector").style.color = "red";
```