# CSS rule to apply only if element has BOTH classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

Let's say we have this markup:

```
<div class="abc"> ... </div>
<div class="xyz"> ... </div>
<div class="abc xyz" style="width: 100px"> ... </div>
```

Is there a way to select only the `<div>` which has BOTH `abc` and `xyz` classes (the last one) AND override its inline width to make the effective width be 200px?

Something like this:

```
[selector] {
  width: 200px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 561, accepted):

```
div.abc.xyz {
    /* rules go here */
}
```

... or simply:

```
.abc.xyz {
    /* rules go here */
}
```

Comment: Also: `.abc.xyz` is more specific than `.abc` or `.xyz` or `div` so `!important` is not necessary.

Comment: So, this will not select `<div class="abc">` because it lacks `xyz`?

Comment: Exactly so. You can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554839/select-css-based-on-multiple-classes for more info.

Comment: @Jan.  !important would be necessary if an inline style is in place.  The inline style from OP's question will override the CSS class.

Comment: @John you are Correct, I misunderstood the question. Still an important part of CSS though that is not understood well enough by most people.

Comment: @esqew: Don't know what to say - amine's exactly the same question. Looked at suggested list of similar questions while entering mine. That should not have come up.

Comment: Note this differs from div .abc .xyz{} which applies to an object with class xyz with its parent having the abc class and the abc class having a div as a parent.

Answer (score 13):

Below applies to all tags with the following two classes

```
.abc.xyz {  
  width: 200px !important;
}
```

applies to div tags with the following two classes

```
div.abc.xyz {  
  width: 200px !important;
}
```

If you wanted to modify this using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.abc.xyz").width("200px");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need a progmatic solution this should work in jQuery:

```
$(".abc.xyz").css("width", 200);
```

Comment: Thank you, seems there was no problem other than my poor grasp over css!

Comment: Jquery internally uses document.queryselector and document.queryselectorall in current releases. So, use those instead of jquery if that is all you would be using jquery for.