# Show and hide div depending on classes

Tags: jquery, css

Pardon this stupid question, I'm not a developer.

I have a div which has either one

```
<div class="blue"></div>
```

or two classes

```
<div class="blue active"></div>
```

In case the class is `blue active` I want to set the div below to `display:block`.
In case the it is `blue` I want to set it to `display:none`.

```
<div class="red"></div>
```

Any idea how to do this with jQuery?

Comment: The question is when do you want to hide/block the div? On page loading? Or on every click on the div?

Comment: You could just use css, depending on the platform (that is, if you have control  over the css)

Comment: I want to hide it on page loading. Class `active` is added or removed dynamically by another script

Comment: Change your css to `.blue ~ .red { display:block; } .blue.active ~ .red { display:none; }` (you might not need the first one, as that's the default)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS rule to apply only if element has BOTH classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796654/css-rule-to-apply-only-if-element-has-both-classes)

Answer (score 0):

> any idea how to do this with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)?

Not all solutions need a javascript solution, in this case a small change to your css is all you need.

```
.blue.active ~ .red { display:none; }
```

This states:  when .blue is also .active then any siblings that are .red will be hidden.

You could also use

```
.blue.active + .red { display:none; }
```

if you know that .red is the very next element.

Example snippet:

```js
$(".blue").click(function() { $(this).toggleClass("active"); });
```

```css
.active { color: blue; }
.blue.active ~ .red { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='blue'>click me</div>
<div class='red'>changes</div>
```

---

As jquery uses css selectors (or close enough) you can do the same with jquery, or use another method to find the .red element, here's some examples where `this` is the .blue element that's changing:

```
// must be the next element
$(this).toggleClass("active").next().toggle();

// next sibling
$(this).toggleClass("active").nextAll(".red").first().toggle();

// may also be before, but must still be a sibling
$(this).toggleClass("active").siblings(".red").toggle();

// red anywhere within the same "wrapper", so doesn't need to be a sibling
// (useful for tables where .wrapper = `tr`)
$(this).toggleClass("active").closest(".wrapper").find(".red").toggle();

// using the same as the css, if `this` is not the .blue element
// but will need additional code to reappear when .blue is not active
$(".blue.active ~ .red").hide();
```

```js
$(".blue").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active")
  $(".red").show();
  $(".blue.active ~ .red").hide();
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='blue'>click me</div>
  <div class='red'>changes</div>
</div>
```