# Ways to add CSS to class2 only if class1 exists?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make class2 {display:none;} but only if class1 exists.

Basically I have an age-gate plugin which, when triggered/visible, is selectable via the "age-gate-form" class.

I want to have another class, "banner", be invisible when age gate is visible/triggered.

Is this doable without touching JS/jQuery?
How is it doable?

I tried to check other answers and google a bit but I'm not sure i've found anything to do exactly what I need.

**EDIT:
2 classes are**

.age-gate-wrapper < If this exists Then

.pum-container {display:none !important;}

---

I tried to

```
.age-gate-wrapper.pum-container {display:none !important;}
```

on the page where both classes existed but it didnt work, pum-container is still visible

The two classes are in different elements (age-gate comes first)

Comment: `.class1.class2 {display:none;}`?

Comment: Where are these class names in relation to each other? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75138822/edit) to show us an example of the HTML structure, including the class names.

Comment: We do need to see relevant HTML. We cannot tell from what you have shown so far where that first class is used in relation to the second one. I assume they are not on the same element, which they would need to be for the code you have shown to work.

Comment: Are you using Popup Maker for both popups? Or a different age gate plugin?

Comment: Not on the same element. Age gate is first, pum is lower in the code

Comment: Is the second a child/descendant of the first or a sibling or neither?

Comment: Neither, unrelated elements. One is one thing, the other's another.

Comment: What plugin are you using for your Age Gate? Beyond that if `.age-gate-wrapper` and `.pum-container` are siblings in the same parent (like the `body`), you could use `.age-gate-wrapper ~ .pum-container { display: none }` - [~ general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)

Comment: Let me try this! Thanks

Comment: Doesnt work - both are in the <body> element.

Comment: .age-gate-wrapper ~ .pum { display: none !important }    fixed!! Post answer for best answer

Comment: @GaryOak added the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this only with CSS and not touch any JS/Jquery, you can do it like this.

> .class1.class2{ display:none; }

This will work only if one item has both of these two classes. You can check the example here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5796669/9914401

Comment: check edits, i added classes

Answer (score 1):

Adding my comment as an answer (since it solved the issue).

Since these are two different elements, you can use the [general sibling selector: ~](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) **since both elements are in the `<body>` tag:**

```
.age-gate-wrapper ~ .pum-container { display: none }
```

If you need to be more specific, or override default styles you can add the `!important` attribute to the property style:

```
.age-gate-wrapper ~ .pum-container { display: none !important}
```

or in your case:

```
.age-gate-wrapper ~ .pum { display: none !important}
```