# CSS: Apply style only to a combination of two classes but no other classes

Tags: jquery, css

Following is what i am using to inject a style which needs to be applied to a Div which has a combination of these two styles : **.noindex** and **.ms-wpContentDivSpace**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.noindex, .ms-wpContentDivSpace')..css({
   overflow: auto,
   height : '150px'
});
});
</script>



<style> 
    .autoScrolListViewWP 
    {   
        HEIGHT: 150px; 
        OVERFLOW: auto 
    } 
</style>
<script> 
    $(document).ready
    (
        function()
        { 
            $('.noindex, .ms-wpContentDivSpace').addClass('autoScrolListViewWP');
        }
    );
</script>
```

Well but what I need is that above new CSS **autoScrolListViewWP** should get added to only those element where css combination is just for these two classes  **.noindex** and **.ms-wpContentDivSpace**

But above script would apply style to any combination of css where those two class exists. E.g. **.ms-WPBody** , **.noindex**  and **ms-wpContentDivSpace autoScrolListViewWP**

My question is how do i identify only a spcific combination of CSS classes ?

Comment: Do you mean [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554839/select-css-based-on-multiple-classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554839/select-css-based-on-multiple-classes)? Then: `.noindex.ms-wpContentDivSpace`.

Comment: `$('.noindex, .ms-wpContentDivSpace')..css({` why is there double dot?

Comment: I need to just target a combination of only those two CSS classes I.e.  .noindex and .ms-wpContentDivSpace. I don't want to set height to 150x adn auto scroll for Div which hare other css classe than those two.

Comment: check at my edit please, now it should work!

Comment: Here the fiddle of my edit, you can check that it work: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/CQw9a/)

Comment: see my reply to your answer, your answer is close but failed in case combination is 'b a c' instead of 'a b c' as you mentioned in your jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CQw9a/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to get all the elements with the two classes, then iterate through them and see if they have other classes. I.e:

```
$('.noindex.ms-wpContentDivSpace').each(function(i, elem) {
    var classes = elem.className.split(/\s+/);
    if (classes.length === 2) { // they should have only these two classes
        $(elem).addClass('autoScrolListViewWP');
        // alternatively elem.className += ' autoScrolListViewWP'; (untested)
    }
});
```

Comment: This seems to be helping, but is it an expensive operation to loop through? or this is the only way out for this problem ?

Comment: Javascript is fast enough for me to not be super worried. There may be a flash of unstyled content, but IMO this is the best you can do under the circumstances

Comment: Ok. I also found another way were i observed that all those Divs i am interested in applying this additional styles are all starting with a unique ID ends with a digit E.g. WebPartWPQ1, WebPartWPQ2,..and so on. So another way for me was to use this selector   $("[id^='WebPartWPQ']").addClass('autoScrolListViewWP');  But because the scope of these question was to select element via CSS classes, I am going to mark your answer as accepted. Thanks for the help Akhaku.

Answer (score 1):

Edit of my previous code:

```
$("[class*='.noindex .ms-wpContentDivSpace']").addClass('autoScrolListViewWP');
```

This should work.

edit: it work, see example: **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/CQw9a/)**

Comment: `*` in general is bad for performance as it will parse every single element in the dom. Filters tend to be slower than average as well, at least on older browsers

Comment: Thanks, but this did not work for me, it still applies style to element where apart from .noindex .ms-wpContentDivSpace i have additional classes.

Comment: @Luca. Read what I wrote plz... I used * because I DONT KNOW WHICH ELEMENT HE USED!!!

Comment: my comment was just a note about using it, not a criticism. Other people might see it and use it without realizing the impact it has. I've read what you wrote and you have no need to scream.

Comment: if someone read what I wrote he use the element and not the `*`. You didn't read!

Comment: to reiterate my point, the answer itself it's not wrong and I do not think deserves a downvote too.

Comment: Hi Andrea, thanks this is really close but this failed in my case where if i have 'b a c' instead of 'a b c', see my update here http://jsfiddle.net/CQw9a/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just take out the space.

```
$('.noindex.ms-wpContentDivSpace').addClass('autoScrolListViewWP');
```

That will add a class only to an element with both the class `noindex` and `ms-ContentDivSpace`.

Yup, jQuery is pretty smart. It's just like using CSS.

**Edit:**

I didn't realize that you wanted to select the element if it *has* those two classes *but no other classes*. That's a little bit trickier.

If you know what class you don't want to include, then this is the easiest (and fastest) way:

```
$('.noindex.ms-wpContentDivSpace').not('.theClassYouDontWant').addClass('autoScrolListViewWP');
```

Comment: Thanks, but this did not work for me, it still applies style to element where apart from .noindex .ms-wpContentDivSpace i have additional classes

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry, I didn't understand your question.

Comment: Edited. I hope that helps!

Comment: i don't know what other classes i need to exclude. So believe i can not go ahead wit the suggested approach. See Andrea Turri reply which is close but fails for one tricky situation.

Answer (score 0):

try

`$('.noindex.ms-wpContentDivSpace').addClass('autoScrolListViewWP');`

that is the standard css trigger for an element who has both classes

Answer (score -2):

In your jQuery call,

```
$('.noindex, .ms-wpContentDivSpace')..css({
```

means each of .noindex   AND each of .ms-wpContentDivSpace

```
$('.noindex.ms-wpContentDivSpace')..css({
```

means .noindex AND .ms-wpContentDivSpace