# CSS Rules that only match when 2 classes coexist

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for something that only happens when 2 classes are present.

Eg:

```
.positive{
  color:#46a546;
}
.positive:after{
  content: "\25b2";
}
.negative{
    color:#F00;
}

.arrow:after{
  content: "\25bc";
}

<span class="positive"> hi </span>
<span class="positiveArrow"> hi </span> 
<span class="negativeArrow"> hi </span> //what i have

<span class="positive arrow"> hi </span>
<span class="negative arrow"> hi </span> // what i want
```

Comment: your question doesn't make sense. Please edit your question.

Comment: 1st hit for "something that only happens when 2 classes are present" is nuclear receptor :D

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554839/select-css-based-on-multiple-classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS:

```
.negative.arrow {
    /* Apply your CSS rules here */
}

.positive.arrow {
    /* Apply your CSS rules here */
}
```