# How to give a css code for combined classes in HTML

Tags: css, html

I have got two classes coming under list "active" and "main-tab-list like  and want to give a css for this combined classes.

Comment: @Vipin, Can you please explain a bit more about what isn't working?

Comment: its about tab making from bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cascade them

```
 .main-tab-list.active{color:red;}
```

This ensures that only .main-tab-list which are active will be selected.
Other classes who also have .active class on it won't be affected.
It simply says, apply this rule to all .main-tab-list classes which at the same time have
.active class

Answer (score 1):

If you want special styles to be applied to elements that have *both* [classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html) then use a rule such as:

```
.active.main-tab-list {/*note there's no space between .active and .main-tab-list*/}
```

If you want the styles to apply to elements that have either of the classes [group them](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#grouping):

```
.active ,
.main-tab-list {/*newline is not required*/}
```

See also [Select element based on multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554839/select-css-based-on-multiple-classes) and http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Answer (score 0):

you can combine it with comma. for example,

```
.active,.main-tab-list{color:red;}
```