# Creating several D3js graphs on same html page

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, visualization

SO I have this html template :-

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
<html>
<head>
<title>Multiple D3 graphs</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<script src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="doc3" class="yui-t7">
  <div id="hd">
    <div id="header"><h1><a href="http://www.free-css.com/free-css-layouts.php">Multigraphs on same page DEMO</a></h1></div>
  </div>
  <div id="bd">
    <div id="yui-main">
      <div class="yui-b">
        <div class="yui-gb">
          <div class="yui-u first">
            <div class="content">GRAPH___1

                 <script>
                   var dataArray=[2,40,50,60];
                   var width = 100;
                   var height = 100;

                   var widthScale = d3.scale.linear()
                                    .domain([0,60])
                                    .range([0,width]);

                    var color = d3.scale.linear()
                                    .domain([0,60])
                                    .range(["red","blue"]);

                    var axis = d3.svg.axis()
                                .ticks(5)
                                .scale(widthScale);


                   var canvas = d3.select("body")
                                .append("svg")
                                .attr("width",width)
                                .attr("height",height)
                                .append("g")
                                .attr("transform","translate(0,0)")

                    var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect") //Selects blank array
                                .data(dataArray) //Where data is coming from and binds data to those rects
                                .enter() //Returns placeholders for each data element for which theres no coresponding DOM element (e "rect" is a DOM), ie if we already had 2 rectangles than data method
                                    .append("rect")
                                    .attr("width", function(d) {return widthScale(d); })
                                    .attr("height",5)
                                    .attr("fill",function(d) {return color(d)})
                                    .attr("y",function(z,i) { return i*10} )

                    canvas.append("g")
                        .attr("transform","translate(0,0)")
                        .call(axis);

                   console.log()
                </script>



            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="yui-u">
            <div class="content">GRAPH__2</div>
          </div>
          <div class="yui-u">
            <div class="content">GRAPH__3</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="yui-b">
      <div id="secondary">Secondary Column</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ft">
    <div id="footer">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you load this page in your browser it will show three panes horizontally tiled.
The thing is that its not displaying the GRAPH__1 inside the first pane. Similarly I would like to insert another D3js graph code in GRAPH__2 and same way for GRAPH__3. Thus I want to show three seperate graphs on the same page , but the position should be as per my need rather than some random location. Please suggest how to get this done.

The stylesheet : styles.css

```
body{text-align:center;}
#ft{clear:both;}
/**/
/* 750 centered, and backward compatibility */ 
#doc,#doc2,#doc3,.yui-t1,.yui-t2,.yui-t3,.yui-t4,.yui-t5,.yui-t6,.yui-t7 {
    margin:auto;text-align:left;
    width:57.69em;*width:56.3em;min-width:750px;}
/* 950 centered */ 
#doc2 {
    width:73.074em;*width:71.313em;min-width:950px;}
/* 100% with 10px viewport side matting */ 
#doc3 {
    margin:auto 10px; /* not for structure, but so content doesn't bleed to edge */
    width:auto;}

/* below required for all fluid grids; adjust widths and margins above accordingly */

    /* to preserve source-order independence for Gecko */
    .yui-b{position:relative;}
    .yui-b{_position:static;} /* for IE < 7 */
    #yui-main .yui-b{position:static;} 

#yui-main {width:100%;}
.yui-t1 #yui-main,
.yui-t2 #yui-main,
.yui-t3 #yui-main{float:right;margin-left:-25em;/* IE: preserve layout at narrow widths */}

.yui-t4 #yui-main,
.yui-t5 #yui-main,
.yui-t6 #yui-main{float:left;margin-right:-25em;/* IE: preserve layout at narrow widths */}

.yui-t1 .yui-b {
    float:left;
    width:12.3207em;*width:12.0106em;}
.yui-t1 #yui-main .yui-b{
    margin-left:13.3207em;*margin-left:13.0106em;
}

.yui-t2 .yui-b {
    float:left;
    width:13.8456em;*width:13.512em;}
.yui-t2 #yui-main .yui-b {
    margin-left:14.8456em;*margin-left:14.512em;
}

.yui-t3 .yui-b {
    float:left;
    width:23.0759em;*width:22.52em;}
.yui-t3 #yui-main .yui-b {
    margin-left:24.0759em;*margin-left:23.52em;
}

.yui-t4 .yui-b {
    float:right;
    width:13.8456em;*width:13.512em;}
.yui-t4 #yui-main .yui-b {
    margin-right:14.8456em;*margin-right:14.512em;
}

.yui-t5 .yui-b {
    float:right;
    width:18.4608em;*width:18.016em;}
.yui-t5 #yui-main .yui-b {
    margin-right:19.4608em;*margin-right:19.016em;
}

.yui-t6 .yui-b {
    float:right;
    width:23.0759em;*width:22.52em;}
.yui-t6 #yui-main .yui-b {
    margin-right:24.0759em;*margin-right:23.52em;
}

.yui-t7 #yui-main .yui-b {
    display:block;margin:0 0 1em 0;
}
#yui-main .yui-b {float:none;width:auto;}
/* GRIDS (not TEMPLATES) */
.yui-g .yui-u, 
.yui-g .yui-g, 
.yui-gc .yui-u,
.yui-gc .yui-g .yui-u,
.yui-ge .yui-u, 
.yui-gf .yui-u{float:right;display:inline;}
.yui-g div.first, 
.yui-gc div.first,
.yui-gc div.first div.first,
.yui-gd div.first, 
.yui-ge div.first, 
.yui-gf div.first{float:left;}
.yui-g .yui-u, 
.yui-g .yui-g{width:49.1%;}
.yui-g .yui-g .yui-u,
.yui-gc .yui-g .yui-u {width:48.1%;}
.yui-gb .yui-u, 
.yui-gc .yui-u, 
.yui-gd .yui-u{float:left;margin-left:2%;*margin-left:1.895%;width:32%;}
.yui-gb div.first, 
.yui-gc div.first, 
.yui-gd div.first{margin-left:0;}
.yui-gc div.first, 
.yui-gd .yui-u{width:66%;}
.yui-gd div.first{width:32%;}
.yui-ge .yui-u{width:24%;}
.yui-ge div.first, 
.yui-gf .yui-u{width:74.2%;}
.yui-gf div.first{width:24%;}
.yui-ge div.first{width:74.2%;}
#bd:after,
.yui-g:after, 
.yui-gb:after, 
.yui-gc:after, 
.yui-gd:after, 
.yui-ge:after, 
.yui-gf:after{content:".";display:block;height:0;clear:both;visibility:hidden;}
#bd,
.yui-g, 
.yui-gb, 
.yui-gc, 
.yui-gd, 
.yui-ge, 
.yui-gf{zoom:1;}

/* Basic Element Formatting */

#header{
    height:100px;
    background-color:#F3F2ED;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }

#header h1{
    font-size:1em;
    margin:0;
    padding:10px;
    }

#header h1 a{
    color:#000000;
    background-color:#F3F2ED;
    }

.content{
    height:300px;
    background:#CCC8B3;
    border-top:#FFFFFF 2px solid;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }

#secondary{
    height:300px;
    background:#F6F0E0;
    border-top:#FFFFFF 2px solid;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }

#secondaryFull{
    height:50px;
    background-color:#CFB59F;
    border-top:#FFFFFF 2px solid;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }

#footer{
    height:50px;
    background:#BFBD93;
    border-top:#FFFFFF 2px solid;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
```

Comment: To append your SVG to the first container, try: `var canvas = d3.selectAll("div.first div.content")`... Also, see [the docs for selections](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#selecting-elements).

Comment: @mdml why does it not work if i use "div.first.div.content" instead ?

Comment: `"div.first div.content"` first selects the `<div>` with class "first", then selects its child `<div>` with class "content". The example you give is chaining the selectors such that you are searching for a `<div>` with classes "first" AND "div" AND "content". See [SO here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554839/select-element-based-on-multiple-classes).