# nth-child selector not working with Wordpress theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-selectors

My goal here is to have each of the boxes (which are testimonial boxes on the live site) have a different color background.
Since it's a Wordpress site, I can't go in and give each box a different id, so I'd like to use the `nth-child()` selector.

I've tried to select the container div and the first box within that container with

```
.row multi-columns-row kwayy-items-wrapper:nth-child(1) .contarea {
    background-color:#555;
}
```

But that isn't doing anything.

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/kf06w3L3/1/)

HTML:

```
    <div class="row multi-columns-row kwayy-items-wrapper">
    <div class=
    "kwayy-testimonial-box col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="kwayy-testimonial-data">
            <blockquote class="kwayy-testimonial-text">
                <div class="contarea">
                    <div class="kwayy-tst-contarea-text">
                        <h2 style="text-align: center;">one</h2>

                        <h4>first box</h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                        consectetur adipiscing elit.
                    </div>
                </div>

                <footer>
                    <span class=
                    "kwayy-testimonial-icon kwicon-fa-quote-left" style=
                    "font-style: italic"></span> <cite class=
                    "kwayy-testimonial-title"></cite>
                </footer>
            </blockquote>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class=
    "kwayy-testimonial-box col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="kwayy-testimonial-data">
            <blockquote class="kwayy-testimonial-text">
                <div class="contarea">
                    <div class="kwayy-tst-contarea-text">
                        <h2 style="text-align: center;">two</h2>

                        <h4>second box</h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                        consectetur adipiscing elit.
                    </div>
                </div>

                <footer>
                    <span class=
                    "kwayy-testimonial-icon kwicon-fa-quote-left" style=
                    "font-style: italic"></span> <cite class=
                    "kwayy-testimonial-title"></cite>
                </footer>
            </blockquote>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class=
    "kwayy-testimonial-box col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="kwayy-testimonial-data">
            <blockquote class="kwayy-testimonial-text">
                <div class="contarea">
                    <div class="kwayy-tst-contarea-text">
                        <h2 style="text-align: center;">three</h2>

                        <h4>third box</h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                        consectetur adipiscing elit.
                    </div>
                </div>

                <footer>
                    <span class=
                    "kwayy-testimonial-icon kwicon-fa-quote-left" style=
                    "font-style: italic"></span> <cite class=
                    "kwayy-testimonial-title"></cite>
                </footer>
            </blockquote>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row multi-columns-row kwayy-items-wrapper:nth-child(1) .contarea {
background-color:#555;
```

}

Thank you.

Comment: If you remove `nth-child` you'll see that your selector still matches nothing.  The issue isn't with `nth-child` but rather the rest of the css selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for nth-child of `.kwayy-testimonial-box`

```
.kwayy-testimonial-box:nth-child(1) .contarea {
    background-color:#555;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kf06w3L3/6/)

Or at least something like this

```
.row.multi-columns-row.kwayy-items-wrapper .kwayy-testimonial-box:nth-child(1) .contarea {
    background-color:#555;
}
```

You have to do a [multiple select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554839/select-element-based-on-multiple-classes)

You also have problems in the selector. You forgot the class selector `.`

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  I had selected the classes as they were listed in the inspector for those elements, but it looks like that is by no means a fool proof method.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error while defining your selectors. It should be rather:

```
.row.multi-columns-row.kwayy-items-wrapper:nth-child(1) .contarea {
    background-color:#555;
}
```

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kf06w3L3/2/)

Answer (score 1):

The classes `multi-columns-row` and `kwayy-items-wrapper` are applied to the same element.

You're also missing `.` in your CSS for those classes.

Change:

```
.row multi-columns-row kwayy-items-wrapper:nth-child(1)
```

To:

```
.row.multi-columns-row.kwayy-items-wrapper:nth-child(1)
```

This is still a poor formation of a selector but it will work in the way you intend it to.