# What does this .something.something selector mean in css?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I found some css code which is using

```
.move.up{
//css goes here
}
```

something like this. Can anyone tell me what type of selector it is in css..??

Comment: It's a combination of two class selectors. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Comment: Also see this related question : [Select element based on multiple classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554839/select-element-based-on-multiple-classes)

Answer (score 5):

It just describes a element with a class move that also has the class up-

`<div class="move up">` <- Selected

`<div class="up move">` <- selected

`<div class="up">` <- Not selected

`<div class="move">` <- Not selected

`<div class="move something up">` <- selected

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/3gkmf3rx/1/

Comment: `<div class="move something up">` must be selected. Please see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#class-html)

Comment: accepted the review too fast

Comment: Yep you are right @Pugazh

Answer (score 1):

It just selects elements with the classes "move" and "up". 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

```css
div{
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: beige;
  border: solid black;
  float:left;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.separator{
  width: 5px;
  height: 60px;
  border: solid black;
  background: grey;
  clear: both;
}



.move.up{
  background: green;
}


//Additional knowledge
.class1 .class2{
  background: orange;
}
span div{
  background: purple;
}

.class3, .class4{
  background: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="separator"></div>
<div class="move">
  1
  </div>
<div class="up">
  2  
</div>
<div class="move up">
  3
</div>
<div class="move classyclass up">
  4
</div>
<div class="separator"></div>

<!-- Additional knowledge :) -->
<div class="class1">
  5
  </div>
<div class="class2">
  6
  </div>
<div class="class1 class2">
  7
  </div>
<div class="class1 classyclass class2">
  8
  </div>
<span>
  <div>8.1</div>
</span>
<div class="separator"></div>
<div class="class3">
  9
  </div>
<div class="class4">
  10
  </div>
<div class="class3 class4">
  11
  </div>
<div class="class3 classyclass class4">
  12
  </div>
```

Comment: Nope, it selects an element with **both** classes, not either. `.move, .up` would select either element

Comment: Thank you. That's what I mean. I've edited my post to make things clear. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

It means an element should have both class `move` and `up`. Multiple className's can be assigned to an HTML element by separating them with space.

Ex: `<a href="#" class="move up">Click here</a>`

More details [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#class-html)