# How to match a particular tag through css selectors where the class attribute contains spaces?

Tags: python, html, css-selectors, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I want to select a `table` tag which has the value of class attribute as:

```
drug-table data-table table table-condensed table-bordered
```

So I tried the below code:

```
for i in soup.select('table[class="drug-table data-table table table-condensed table-bordered"]'):
    print(i)
```

But it fails to work:

> ValueError: Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "table[class="drug-table"

spaces in the class attribute value is the cause for not getting a match. And also, I want to go through two more elements depth like:

```
soup.select('table[class="drug-table data-table table table-condensed table-bordered"] > tr > th')
```

Comment: Have you tired `find_all`?

Comment: I hate findall.. ya findall works.. But I want css selectors..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To specify [multiple classes in a CSS selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554839/select-element-based-on-multiple-classes), join them with dots:

```
soup.select("table.drug-table.data-table.table.table-condensed.table-bordered")
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> data = """
... <table class="drug-table data-table table table-condensed table-bordered">
...     <tr>
...         <td>test</td>
...     </tr>
... </table>
... """
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
>>> for i in soup.select("table.drug-table.data-table.table.table-condensed.table-bordered > tr > td"):
...     print(i)
... 
<td>test</td>
```