# Parsing html using Selenium - class name contains spaces

Tags: python, html, parsing, selenium, text

I'm trying to parse some **html** using **Selenium**. The problem is that it raises **error** in case the class name contains spaces.

Here is the tag I'm searching for: `<p class="p0 ng-binding">text</p>`

I've tried these two options:

```
result.find_element_by_class_name('departure').find_element_by_css_selector('p.p0 ng-binding').text 

result.find_element_by_class_name('departure').find_element_by_class_name('p0 ng-binding').text 

>>> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: The given selector p0 ng-binding is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Compound class names not permitted
```

Could anybody give me a hint?

Comment: That's two class names.

Comment: An do you know how to find the class?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `p` element has two classes: `p0` and `ng-binding`.

Try this selector:

```
find_element_by_css_selector('p.p0.ng-binding')
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue Compound class names not permitted occurs because the class name has multiple words you can resolve this by using the below css-selectors

```
CssSelector("[class*='p0 ng-binding']"); //or
CssSelector("[class='p0 ng-binding']");
```

Hope this helps you.Kindly get back if you have any queries

Answer (score 2):

As @eee pointed out, to check [multiple classes in a CSS selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554839/select-element-based-on-multiple-classes), join them with dots:

```
p.p0.ng-binding
```

The problem with that though is that `ng-binding` class is not a good choice to base your locator on. Instead, check the `p0` class only:

```
p.p0
```