# What value does any Selenium expected condition return? And how do i use this with an IF statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So im running this piece of code, basically you enter a code and press a button and then the page redirects if the code is correct.

So i want the code to detect if an image on that page disappears using "invisibility_of_element_located" (So that i can tell if the page has loaded) which works fine when used alone, however i want to use it in an if statement, such that if the element does go invisible:

print(something)

However i cant seem to figure out how to set it up in such a way.
I've tried making it == True but still got nothing.
I've also tried using it in try except loops but essentially i dont know what it returns so i cant use it properly.

```py
if WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "NXVPg Szr5J coreSpriteLock "))) == True:
            print("Now its loaded")
        else:
            print("Nope not loaded")
```

When using it as above, with or without the == True it straight away prints the response of ("Now its loaded") Even if the page hasnt actually changed. However when used like this:

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "NXVPg Szr5J coreSpriteLock ")))
print("Now its loaded")
```

It does actually wait and works properly, only problem is i cant use an else to show it hasnt loaded, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WebDriverWait` will wait for a maximum of *x* seconds until the condition is met. If the condition is not met it will throw a `TimeoutException`. In other words, the `if` block will never reach the `else` branch if the condition fails.

Go for a `try-except` structure:

```
from selenium.common import exceptions as SE

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((*<By relevant identification method here>*)))
    print("Now its loaded")
except SE.TimeoutException:
    print("Nope not loaded")
```

Note `By.CLASS_NAME` is not the right one to use as you have multiple class names (`"NXVPg Szr5J coreSpriteLock "`). An example of a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953529/parsing-html-using-selenium-class-name-contains-spaces).

Use either `By.CSS_SELECTOR` or `By.XPATH` instead:

```
By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".NXVPg.Szr5J.coreSpriteLock "
#or
By.XPATH, "//*[@class='NXVPg Szr5J coreSpriteLock ']"
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear-up: After testing and debugging more, i found this out too! Question: why shouldn't i use class_name because there is only one class with the name "NXVPg Szr5J coreSpriteLock " when i checked.

Comment: A single class name cannot contain spaces. So what you see there are several class names. `.find_element_by_class_name()` or EC `By.CLASS_NAME` matches on single class name. Here's [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771604/selenium-compound-class-names-not-permitted) on handling this type of situation.

Comment: Ahhh i never knew this, cool thanks so much! Appreciated greatly!