# d3.select element with multiple ids

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I think my approach here is off.

I had code that worked:

```
$('.rectangle').mouseenter(function () {
     var rect = d3.select("#"+this.id)
     rect.transition()
         .duration(500)
         .attr("width", 40)
         .attr("height", 400);
       });
```

Then, I added a second id to each element, and the functionality broke. I've tried various ways of selecting an element that has multiple ids, since that seems to be the problem; none of them worked.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554839/select-element-based-on-multiple-classes) has suggestions that seem to work for multiple classnames, but these approaches don't work for multiple ids.

I'd thought that adding the second id was cleaner code, but and then I had to add a second id to each d3 element so that each one could be selected by either unique property - word or element number.

Is there a way in d3 to select an element that has multiple ids?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: You can't have multiple IDs for an element -- by definition, an ID is a unique identifier for an element (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192048/can-an-html-element-have-multiple-ids)). You can achieve the same functionality by assigning multiple classes (just add classes instead of IDs).

Comment: Cool. Thanks - I got fooled because jQuery accepted it so happily.