# how to give a second css attribute an ::before element

Tags: html, css

Hey I'm using webflow to create my web project. Webflow gives active links an class called `.w--current`, that's their "active". So the link class looks like this when a webpage is open `.nav__link .w--current`.

How can I give in this specific case the `.w--current` element an ::before pseudo? I tried all kind of ways like `.nav__link .w--current::before` or `.nav__link:before .w--current:before` but none of them worked. Can I generally add an pseudo element to an CSS class which is at the second position?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554839/select-element-based-on-multiple-classes

Comment: You've misidentified the problem. It's the descendant combinator you've put between the class selectors. Nothing to do with the pseudo-element.

Comment: What did you try? Show the CSS you tried to apply as well as a simple HTML markup. It could be as simple as you didn't add the `content` property to the pseudo element.

Comment: Or if there is only ever one element with class `w--current` at any one time, just `.w--current` for a selector will do.

Answer (score 1):

The empty space between both classes was my problem.

The correct solution is: `.nav__link.w--current:before`