# .after function JQuery is not working with div class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to add div after another div with `class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 stm-filter_transmission"`. How should I do that?
This is not working:

```
<script>
$(function (){ 
    $( ".col-md-12 col-sm-6 stm-filter_transmission" ).after( "<p>Test</p>" );
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Change `".col-md-12 col-sm-6 stm-filter_transmission"` to `".col-md-12.col-sm-6.stm-filter_transmission"`. In both CSS and jQuery, to select an element with multiple classes you concatenate them with `.` and no space. The space means select a descendant. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554839/select-element-based-on-multiple-classes

Comment: Thanks. My main problem was `jQuery: $ is not a function` but I have solved it already.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I select an element with multiple classes in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/how-can-i-select-an-element-with-multiple-classes-in-jquery)